# Angular input 'required' is always false

Tags: angular, forms

**THE PROBLEM:**

when logout() method is fired up from Error Handler and user gets to "Login" page, fields are always invalid (based on 'required' property).

When logout() method is fired up from, let's say, regular logout button - there is no problems, and after putting some values to input fields - they get valid.

Error handler with a method:

```
  handleError(error: any): void {

const authService = this.injector.get(AuthenticationService);

switch (error.status) {
  case 403:
    if(authService.isLoggedIn()){
      alert('Your session has expired!');
      authService.logout();
    }
    break;

  default:
    alert('Error Handler:\n\nError has occur. Status=' + error.status +
      '\n\nError has occur. Stack=' + error.stack);
}
}
```

logout() method:

```
  logout(): void {
console.log('>> logout()');
// clear token remove user from local storage to log user out
localStorage.removeItem('token');
this.router.navigate(['login']);
}
```

Here is an excerpt from "Login" component:

```
<mat-card class="login">
    <input required [(ngModel)]="model.email" name="username" placeholder="Username" (input)="test()">

    <input type="password" required [(ngModel)]="model.password" name="password" placeholder="Password" (input)="test()">

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!loginForm.form.valid">Login
    </button>

  </mat-card>
```

Comment: Have you checked differences in you formGroup object? maybe logging this will give us a hint.

Comment: @itdoesntwork  I tried: `@ViewChild('loginForm') public loginForm: NgForm;` and `test() {
    console.log(this.loginForm.valid);
  }` the result is correct - when it has to be true - it is true.